# How can I hide sim card feature reference in notification area

Tags: samsung

In every samsung phone that have 2 sim card enabled, you will see a small reference to tell which sim doing what

But no thanks, I know which sim doing what on my phone, you doesn't need to remind me that every single time I've glanced my notification bar, samsung

How can I hide this reference? Thanks

[image]